# How to migrate parity from one system to another

Tags: parity-wallet

I have parity installed and running in computer1.
Suppose I need to access my wallet from computer2, what should be done?

Answer (score 1):

From the shared link in the other answer:

> The Parity recovery phrase is a 12-word mnemonic phrase allowing you
> to have an additional backup. It's displayed once after account
> creation and should be written down or printed out and kept in a safe
> place. This phrase is not protected with any password or encryption
> and should always kept offline and cold. In the rare case that your
> encrypted backups (see below) are corrupted or lost, the phrase allows
> you to fully recover your private key.
>
> ## Exporting accounts via the Wallet UI
>
> The most convenient way to backup your accounts is via the wallet UI
> which offers direct export of the encrypted key files in JSON format.
>
> #### A single account
>
> To backup a single account, just open your accounts view, click the
> account you wish to export, and find the EXPORT button.
>
> *Once you enter your passphrase and confirm, the key will be exported and downloaded to your disk.*
>
> #### All accounts at once
>
> To backup multiple accounts, or all accounts at once, just open your
> accounts view and find the EXPORT button.
>
> *Toggle which accounts you wish to export by clicking them, and thus enabling or disabling the account export.*
>
> *Enter the password for each account you wish to export and confirm.*
>
> ## Restoring options
>
> Restoring options work analogue to the backup options explained above.
>
> ### Wallet UI
>
> The user interface allows you to import keys from:
>
> - Geth Keystore: This allows importing keys created in with the    go-ethereum client.
> - JSON Backup: This allows importing    password-encrypted JSON key-files previously exported with Parity.
> - Private Keys: This allows importing plain, unencrypted private keys    generated with any other application.
> - Presale Wallet: This allows importing a wallet from the initial Ether pre-sale maintained by the Ethereum Foundation.
>
>   In addition, it's possible to restore private    keys from the 12-word mnemonic recovery phrase.

Comment: OP, I believe (as in, I haven't verified) that the backup phrases only apply to newer versions of Parity; older versions of Parity did not use HD wallets and thus do not have that option. The other options should be available regardless of version.

Answer (score -2):

Please see this How-To that describes the process very nicely.

https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Backing-up-&-Restoring

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi there. Can you summarise the important parts of the process from the link? If the link goes dead, or is moved, then your answer is no longer useful. (Which is why link-only answers are discouraged.)

Comment: Good point. Will consider this in the future for sure.

Comment: Link down, as noted